# how to print the solutions of game24 in order

Tags: c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int flag = 0;
char myArr[3];
int myChar;
int changeEl[4];


 
void swap(int *a, int *b) {
  int h = (*a);
  (*a) = (*b);
  (*b) = h;
}

void Cal24 (int arr[4], int pointer, int sum, char myArr[3], char ch, int charrpoint) {
  if (pointer != 0) {
    myArr[pointer - 1] = ch;
  }
  
  if (sum == 24 && pointer == 3) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4;  i++) {
      printf("%d", changeEl[i]);
      if (i < 3) {
        printf(" %c ", myArr[i]);
      }
    }
    flag = 1;
    return;
  }
 
  
  if (pointer <= 3 && flag == 0) {
    Cal24(arr, pointer+1, sum * arr[pointer+1], myArr, '*', charrpoint);
    Cal24(arr, pointer+1, sum + arr[pointer+1], myArr, '+', charrpoint);
    if (sum >= arr[pointer+1]) {
      Cal24(arr, pointer+1, sum - arr[pointer+1], myArr, '-', charrpoint);
    } else {
      Cal24(arr, pointer+1, arr[pointer+1] - sum, myArr, '-', charrpoint + 1);
    }
    if (sum >= arr[pointer + 1] && sum % arr[pointer + 1] == 0) {
      Cal24(arr, pointer+1, sum / arr[pointer+1], myArr, '/', charrpoint);
    } else if (sum < arr[pointer + 1] && arr[pointer + 1] % sum == 0){
      Cal24(arr, pointer+1, arr[pointer+1] / sum, myArr, '/', charrpoint);
    }
  }
}


void permute(int index, int *arr) {
  if (index == 4 && flag == 0) {
      for (int a = 0; a < 4; a++) {
        changeEl[a] = arr[a];
      }
    Cal24(arr, 0, arr[0], myArr, myChar, 0);
  }
  
  
  for (int i = index; i < 4; i++) {
    swap(arr + index, arr + i);
    permute(index + 1, arr);
    swap(arr + index, arr + i);
  }
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  int num, arr[4];

  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    scanf("%d", &num);
    arr[i] = num;
  }
  
  permute(0, arr);
  
  if (flag == 0) {
    printf("NO SOLUTIONS");
  }
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Given 4 random numbers from 1-10 the result has to be 24 using (*, /, +, -). I find out all permutations and pass them into a recursive function to try out all combinations if the result is 24.

My problem is that I want to print the solution. For example for input: 1 2 4 6 the output should be (2-1) * 4 * 6. My output is 1 - 2 * 4 * 6

Comment: Your code has some undefined behavior.  You can't access `arr[pointer + 1]` when `pointer` is 3 because your array only has 4 members.  With your code as it is, when I run it on Windows sometimes it crashes and sometimes it prints "2 - 1 * 4 * 6".

Comment: Can you state clearly in English what "game24" is, or provide a link to a description?  I'd like to know the rules and goals.

Comment: So the input is 4 random numbers from 1-10 and the output is if the result can be 24 using multiplication, addition,division and subtraction. For example for the input 5 6 7 7, the output should be ((5-(7/7)) * 6). For 1 1 1 1 the output should be no solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Cacl24 is a game we use to play as a child. It's a good question to practice programming. You can add a variable to remember the path taken to arrive at a success.

For every permutation of the four numbers, there can be 4^3 ways to assign operators in between.

Let's say, you have 1,2,3,4
and let's consider the permutation 1,2,3,4

you will have 4^3 ways to insert operators in between.

Let's consider the case

`1 + 2 + 3 + 4`

Now, you can add parenthesis to determine which operation will occur fist, etc., there are:

```
((1+2)+3)+4
(1+2)+(3+4)
(1+(2+3))+4
1+((2+3)+4)
1+(2+(3+4))
```

Let's hope I have exhausted all ways of parenthesising the expression.

Now, you remember the permutation, the operators, and the parenthesising choice, it should be very easy to print your final expression.

If you want more chanllege, you can try to simplify your expression by removing parenthesises that can be done without;

Or maybe find all unique solution to a set of numbers.

Comment: Yes, but the problem arises when the operation is s - or /. For example for 5 6 7 7 the answer should be (5-(7/7)) * 6, but my program prints 7/7 - 5 * 6, because division and subtraction have 2 paths either a - b or b - a, then my output is printed wrong

Comment: @Manos: That's not a problem. As you will go through all permutations of the numbers (potentially), you will encounter 5,7,7,6 anyways, which can be parenthesised as (5-(7/7))*6.

Comment: Your list of 5 parenthesis options is indeed exhaustive.  There are 6 (3 factorial) orders to perform the three different operations, but two of them are mathematically the same (left-right-middle and right-left-middle).

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what is going on in your code and it was doing undefined behavior so I rewrote everything using my own approach.  The memory used in the variable-length arrays is O(N^2).  I hope the code makes sense.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

// Struct representing an arithmetical expression.
typedef struct Expr {
  char type;  // #, +, -, *, /
  int value;
  const struct Expr * left;
  const struct Expr * right;
} Expr;

void print_expr(const Expr * expr, char context) {
  if (expr == NULL) { return; }  // shouldn't happen

  if (expr->type == '#') {
    printf("%d", expr->value);
  }
  else {
    putchar('(');
    print_expr(expr->left, expr->type);
    putchar(expr->type);
    print_expr(expr->right, expr->type);
    putchar(')');
  }
}

void search_list(const Expr * list, int length);

void operate_then_search(const Expr * list, int length,
  int left_index, int right_index, char operation) {

  Expr new_list[length - 1];

  const Expr * left = list + left_index;
  const Expr * right = list + right_index;

  int value = 0;
  switch (operation) {
  case '+': value = left->value + right->value; break;
  case '-': value = left->value - right->value; break;
  case '*': value = left->value * right->value; break;
  case '/':
    if (right->value == 0) { return; }
    value = left->value / right->value;
    if (value * right->value != left->value) { return; }
    break;
  }

  new_list[0] = (Expr){ operation, value, left, right };

  int insert_index = 1;
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if (i == left_index || i == right_index) { continue; }
    new_list[insert_index++] = list[i];
  }

  search_list(new_list, length - 1);
}

// This iterates over all possible operations that can be performed on the
// members of the given list of expressions.  Each operation results in a list
// of expressions that is shorter by one, and we call search_list recursively
// on each of those lists.  Once we reach a list of length 1, we check to see
// if its value is 24 and thus represents a solution.
void search_list(const Expr * list, int length) {
  if (length == 1) {
    if (list->value == 24) {
      print_expr(list, 0);
      putchar('\n');
      fflush(stdout);
    }
    return;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
      if (i == j) { continue; }
      if (i < j) {
        operate_then_search(list, length, i, j, '+');
        operate_then_search(list, length, i, j, '*');
      }
      operate_then_search(list, length, i, j, '-');
      operate_then_search(list, length, i, j, '/');
    }
  }
}

void search_ints(int * int_list, int length) {
  Expr list[length];
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    list[i] = (Expr){ '#', int_list[i] };
  }
  search_list(list, length);
}

int main(int argc, const char ** argv) {
  int arr[] = { 2, 1, 4, 6 };
  search_ints(arr, sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int));
}
```

This program produces the following output:

```c
(((2-1)*4)*6)
(((2-1)*6)*4)
((4/(2-1))*6)
((4*6)*(2-1))
((4*6)/(2-1))
((6/(2-1))*4)
((4-1)*(2+6))
((2+6)*(4-1))
((2-1)*(4*6))
((4*6)/(2-1))
```

Currently there are lots of solutions in this list that are essentially the same.  It should be possible to impose more restrictions on the order of operations to eliminate the duplicates.  That's what my `i < j` condition does, but that measure alone isn't nearly enough.